# How to show soft-keyboard when MultiAutoCompleteTextView is focused

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have already tried the usual but it's not working:

```
multiEdit.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(multiEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Notice my `getActivity()`. That's because I am using `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` inside a DialogFragment. And the snippet is inside `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me reliably. It focuses the view automatically. No additional work necessary.

```
multiEdit.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            multiEdit.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
            multiEdit.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));

        }
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: On Samsung Galaxy S9 you should use at least 400ms. It doesn't look like a good code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
multiEdit.requestFocus();
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping: +1. But I find one that works for me quite reliably. I will post it.

Comment: With only TextViews, EditTexts and Buttons in all my layouts when using the code above I always has the keyboard shows up. But if something works for you then I now learn there is another way.